# Mixing essay-like opinions with the story

Tags: fiction, style, novel, essay

Is it very uncommon or out of place to mix your own opinions within the story lines?

Is it uncommon to change the tone from third person and talk to the reader directly?

I have read many tips on letting the readers come to conclusions themselves.  But sometimes it helps talking to the reader directly and describe how the characters feel. Or sometimes it just helps to make a quick point within the story. Any tips on this?

Is there any name for this style?

Here is an example:

> As he hugged her one more time, Andrew whispered: "I'm sure I'll see
>   you soon Linda", knowing very well that this is the last time they will ever
>   meet. She nodded and vaguely smiled at him without saying anything. He touched her face, kissed her on the lips and left.
>
> There is a moment in your life that you make a hard choice, knowing the consequences might hurt someone, but you still make it because of a greater good. In those situations if you respect them you try to be as honest as possible. Andrew, however, couldn't help but lying. He lied not to make it easier for Linda, but to make it easier on himself. Looking her in the eyes and telling the truth was beyond his courage.

Answer (score 3):

If the reader is firmly in the character's POV, and expects to remain firmly in the character's POV, this is jarring and can throw the reader right out of the story.

If the reader is firmly in an omniscient, opinionated narrator's POV, and is prepared to dip in and out of characters' heads, this works just fine.

For this to work, you have to prep the reader to expect it. Begin the pattern early in the story, and do it often enough that the reader experiences it as part of the tone of the story.

Note: Given that dipping in and out of characters' heads is **very** difficult to do well...

Another alternative is to stay firmly in the character's head, to put the dilemma into the POV character's thoughts. In your example, the moment between the hug and the lie are a perfect spot for that.

The reader will understand that this is a universal thing. And putting it into the POV character's thoughts keeps it personal, and helps the reader to *experience* the principle rather than merely reading about it.

Odd but true: The more personal you make a dilemma for the character, the more universal it becomes for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Never liked the stories with mixed lines – it’s confusing because you never know whether the author hints at the character's thoughts or share their own.
PS.The more personal an author makes a dilemma for the character, the more his different stories